# ¿Qué dice el gaucho típico?

Tags: vocabulario, dialectos

Un estudiante mío quiere saber cómo se dice "yeehaw," una expresión común entre los vaqueros norteamericanos. ¿Hay un grito similar para los gauchos?

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre que el equivalente es

> ¡Huija! (ver [esta nota](https://www.clarin.com/sociedad/grito-huija-gauchos-coparon-centro-ciudad_0_S1Of1hkWAFe.html)  )

Popularmente la interjección {de raíz indígena tehuelche) fue en un tiempo conocida gracias a un personaje de historietas argentino muy famoso, [Patoruzú](http://www.todohistorietas.com.ar/patoruzu.htm)

Comment: Tenés razón: la palabra es "huija", y es muy probable que derive fonéticamente de "yeehaw", así como la "chuenga" (un caramelo en forma de nudo que se vendía en las canchas) es una deformación fonética de "chewing gum".

Comment: Los campesinos chilenos usaban el grito _¡huija!_ (o mejor: _¡güija!_) para arrear el ganado, y la interjección se sigue diciendo en canciones tradicionales. Hay una típica que dice _Huija, rendija, la mama, la hija..._. Es innegablemente de origen local (tehuelche, como dices), nada de vaqueros norteamericanos, no señor.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que hubiera una interjección similar entre los gauchos de las pampas. (Uso "hubiera" y no "haya" porque en realidad no quedan muchos gauchos.)

Las dos interjecciones que se me ocurren son:

Achalay: expresa admiración o felicidad.

Ahijuna: (aijuna) contracción de "ah, hijo de una..." expresa sorpresa, alegría, pena, etc.

[Fuente](http://www.folkloredelnorte.com.ar/terminos.htm)